# Can I avoid capital gains tax if I sell only the amount I put in and leave the rest?

Tags: united-states, investing, capital-gains-tax

I haven't found a definite written answer, probably because it is implied. However, I'd really love confirmation if anyone can verify my assumption, before I make a decision.

Say I bought 10 shares of a stock at $10/share, for a total cost of $100. Now the stock is worth $20/share. Can I sell 5 shares, effectively pulling out the original $100 I put in and leave the other 5 shares to continue to grow in value **without having to pay ANY capital gains tax at all?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No - stocks are bought and sold in shares, not dollar amounts, so the 5 shares you sold would have a cost basis of $50 and a sold value of $100 for a capital gain of $50.

Comment: Whew - I'm so glad I decided to ask! I didn't at all consider capital gains being determined on a per share basis. I assumed it was strictly by the realized dollar amount gained (or lost). Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: @Narm -- "on a per share basis" uses the key term here (but with a different meaning): from an accounting perspective, your **basis** is the cost of whatever it is that you sold, with some adjustments that don't apply here. Profit is the amount you sold it for minus the basis.